# Why doesn't VS Code suggest methods for a specific type for the return value of json.load?

Tags: python, json, function, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Any ideas why this particular function (`.update`- a `dict` method) does not pop up with IntelliSense?

```py
import json

dic = {
   "cool": {
      "moose": "cheese",
   }
}

with open("newfile.json", "r") as data_file:
   data: dict = json.load(data_file)
   data.update
```

The other `json` functions seem to populate just fine.

Comment: The title asks about `json.load()`, but the post seems to ask about a different method `data.update()`.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) reads the JSON file and returns the contents as a Python object. From the docs:

> Deserialize *fp* (a `.read()`-supporting [text file](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-text-file) or [binary file](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-binary-file) containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

The return type for IntelliSense is `Any`, which is to be expected, since *static* analysis wouldn't be able to know what you'd get from parsing a file whose contents will be read at *runtime*. The file could be read so the return value is a `dict`. Or it could be a `list`. Or a `str`, `int`, `float`, `True`, `False`, or `None` (see the above linked conversion table). That's why the type is `Any`. `Any` covers all of those.

To get IntelliSense to give you suggestions for `dict` methods, you need to give an indication that you actually want that, which you can do with [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) like so: `data: dict = json.load(data_file)`.

Better yet, insert a runtime type-check:

```py
if type(data) == dict:
   data.update(dic)
```

Static analysis will know that inside that if-block's body, the type of `data` must be `dict`, because that's the only way execution can reach it at runtime.