# Python 3: is there a way for static analyzers (e.g. VS Code Intellisense) to recognize classes created through class factories?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-typing

I have the following code.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import *


class ExampleClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self):
        pass


def class_factory(s: str) -> Type[ExampleClass]:
    class SpecificClass(ExampleClass):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def get(self):
            return s

    return SpecificClass


ASubclass = class_factory("A") 
BSubclass = class_factory("B")


def f(x: ASubclass):
    pass
```

In VS Code, in `f`, the type annotation `ASubclass` has a red underline with the message

```
Variable not allowed in type expressionPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

When I hover over the definition of ASubclass, VS Code is able to recognize that it is a `Type[ExampleClass]`, so I would expect at the very least when coding `f`, typing something like `x.` would give `.get()` as a suggestion, but when I hover over `x`, VS Code tells me `x: Unknown`.

What I want is the behavior of VS Code (or any static analyzer) with this code, without having to potentially write out tens or hundreds of potentially similar classes.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import *


class ExampleClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self):
        pass


class ASubclass(ExampleClass):
    def get(self):
        return "A"
    

class BSubclass(ExampleClass):
    def get(self):
        return "B"


def f(x: ASubclass):
    pass
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: loosely related (also questions about Python and related to static analysis): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76018041/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75998536/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77228321/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to go on this - an important thing to remember is that types can't borrow information from runtime behaviour. The reason your above example doesn't work is that it's trying to use a runtime type as a type alias.

### Solution 1: Use the base class

The simplest way to go, is probably to use `ExampleClass` as the type in `f` - it doesn't tell the user that the `get` method returns `"A"`, but otherwise it does the job:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import *


class ExampleClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self) -> str:
        ...


def class_factory(s: str) -> type[ExampleClass]:
    class SpecificClass(ExampleClass):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def get(self) -> str:
            return s

    return SpecificClass


ASubclass = class_factory("A") 
BSubclass = class_factory("B")


def f(x: ExampleClass):
    pass

f(ASubclass())
```

### Solution 2: Use TypeVar

So for whatever reason, let's suppose you really need to know the type on the get return is more specific than just string. `TypeVar` can come to our aid here. We can use it to specify the return type of get varies depending on the inheritance structure using `Generic`, and this allows us to specify a class where the return type of get is specifically the string `"A"`:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, Literal, LiteralString, TypeVar


GetReturn = TypeVar("GetReturn", bound=LiteralString)
class ExampleClass(Generic[GetReturn], ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self) -> GetReturn:
        ...


def class_factory(s: GetReturn) -> type[ExampleClass[GetReturn]]:
    class SpecificClass(ExampleClass):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def get(self) -> GetReturn:
            return s

    return SpecificClass

ASubclass = class_factory("A") 

def f(x: ExampleClass[Literal["A"]]):
    pass

f(ASubclass())
```

Personally I would probably use Solution 1 in most cases, but how specific you need the type hint depends on your use case. Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn. One thing that's nice about python is in general you'll never *need* repetitive code. Guess that's not the case here.